# Creating an array with user input

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a code that lets the user determine the size and elements of an array and then print it out. So far I have this.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class test3 {

  public static void main (String[] args)
  { 
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input how many numbers you want to find the median for (numerical value) :");
    int num = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter " + num + " numbers.");
    int[] values = new int[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        values[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println(values[i]);


    }
  }
}
```

I don't know if it is right because when a user inputs the size and then the elements, the code is just displaying the element as the user inputs it. For example,

input how many numbers you want to find the median for

5

please enter 5 numbers

3//user input

3//what is displayed.

I want to make it so that the user inputs all of their numbers and THEN it displays the inputed numbers as an array.

We are not allowed to use the array class by the way.

Comment: If you want to display the values *after* the user has entered all the numbers, then the System.out.println() should be... after the user has entered all the numbers, i.e. after the for loop.

Comment: `We are not allowed to use the array class` you are using an array right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> import java.util.Scanner;
>
> public class test3 {
>
> public static void main (String[] args)   {
>
> ```
> Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
>
> System.out.println("Input how many numbers you want to find the median for (numerical value) :");
> int num = keyboard.nextInt();
> System.out.println("Please enter " + num + " numbers.");
> int[] values = new int[num];
> for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
>     values[i] = keyboard.nextInt();        
> }
>
> for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
>     System.out.println(values[i]);        
>     }
>
>    } 
> }
> ```

Comment: you are welcome, if this worked then please accept this answer )
For more information about accepting answer you can read here:
http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop will execute for as many number as the user has entered, in your test case 5. Every iteration will take a number from the keyboard input, place it into the array and display it. Since you want to capture all the numbers first and then want to display them you should remove

```
System.out.println(values[i]);
```

from the for loop and place that into another for loop to display the numbers like so

```
for(int x=0 ;i < num ; i++)
{
  System.out.println(values[x]);
}
```

This way the first loop will gather all the numbers and after the numbers are collected the second loop will display the numbers one by one iterating over the array.

Hope this helps!